# How to remove old light switches, leave circuit always on?

Tags: switch

I have purchased Hue lights and switches and want to remove my old wired switches, leaving the circuits always connected.  (Thereby using the Hue software switches to control the lights.)

I suppose I need to remove the old switches and connect their wires together.  Some of the old switches are simple one switch per light, others are two switches for a light.  Are there any tricks to this, or do I just turn off the circuit breaker, remove the switch, connect all the wires together (except the ground obviously), then cross my fingers and turn on the circuit breaker?

Thanks much for any advice!

Comment: Are these single-pole switches, or are there any multi-way switches involved?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I googled those terms and I think I understand the question :)  Yes there are single pole and also two 3-way switch pairs.  I assume that I'm going to need to connect the same traveler on each side of the 3-ways and leave the other traveler unconnected?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to consider the Electrical Code, which absolutely requires a light switch in the expected location, and requires that the switch turn on a light.  (in some cases this can be a switched receptacle, but the homeowner is expected to fit a light there.)

Why should light switches be required?  Why can't you choose to turn your lights on any way you please?  **First responders.**

- an EMT who needs to reach you right now
- a fireman trying to find your child or pet
- a SWAT team needing to see your hands do not contain a gun

If any of these guys have to pause to fiddle with lights, that might not go your way.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, just to be clear, I'm not eliminating any switching, I'm just converting from wired to wireless.  I will place wireless switches on the top of blank plates where the wired switches used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the old switches, at least until you get the Hue lights working perfectly. If the old switches are removed, you will have to place a removable blank cover plate on each box. I think you can get a guard to keep the switch from being flipped. There are different types but here is one [model](http://hardwareonlinestore.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=25720&virtuemart_category_id=33303&gclid=CjwKEAiAqozEBRDJrPem0fPKtX0SJAD5sAyHNFMAIpQ5EU689T9Sru6jeouFRvdknLMOT2f7Kz8sLxoC-Ffw_wcB&ppcsclkid=N4nV0vy9nJWY&ppcstrkid=1332290283&ppcsu=xhg7f5djqitnahs). Google "light switch guard". Some screw on and some are magnetic.

Comment: Thanks, I have those Hues working the way I want.  I showed my wife the light switch guard solution, and she isn't a fan.  I intend to place the blank cover plate on the switch box, then use the adhesive on the back of the Hue switches to put them on top of the plate.

Comment: Do these Hue switches have a recession on the back side so that they could fit over an existing manual toggle switch? The remotes for Hunter fans have a holder that is recessed and will cover a manual toggle switch. But in installing some of them I took out the switches and connected the hots together with twist on connectors.  Then I later reinstalled the switches for reasons that I don't need to explain here. But these old mechanical switches don't fail. Why not leave them in place in case someone at a later time wants them.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I googled that hunter remote, that's a pretty slick system.  Unfortunately Hue lights only come with a flat back.  I may be out buying switches again sometime, but I think I'm going to gut them for now.Thanks for your input!